# Python robotparser not returning true or false

Tags: python

I'm playing around with the robotparses library, and I'm trying out the example program from:

http://docs.python.org/library/robotparser.html

My code is currently-

```
import robotparser

def TestMain():

    #Check robots.txt

    rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    rp.set_url("http://www.musi-cal.com/robots.txt")
    rp.read()
    rp.can_fetch("*", "http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/search?city=San+Francisco")
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I run the code it runs successfully, but doesn't return anything, anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: your function doesn't have a return statement, how are you calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you are refering to is for interactive use in the [interpreter](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) and not a standalone program. You can't produce anything meaningful just by adding a `def` statement. For your function to return something there has to be an `return` statement. And to use  a function you have to call it.

Here's a [python book](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/python.html) that should explain how to construct functions and turn them into programs.

Comment: Right, thanks. New to Python, still making mistakes on the basics.